# Melpa package Ebib does not appear on the package list

Tags: package-repositories

I'd like to install the *Ebib* package, whose official homepage is: https://joostkremers.github.io/ebib/. According to the *Installation* section on this homepage,

> The easiest way to install Ebib is to use Melpa.

So I installed Melpa by following the instructions given in the *Installing Melpa* section of the following page: https://melpa.org/#/getting-started

I restarted Emacs, and executed `M-x package-list-packages`. The resulting list included packages for which *melpa* was specified in the *Archive* column. However, the package *ebib* was not on the list.

How can I install the *Ebib* package?

Comment: Try to `M-x package-refresh-contents`?

Answer (score 1):

After closing and opening Emacs a few times, and executing `M-x package-list-packages` every time, the *Ebib* package eventually appeared. Then it disappeared again. Then reappeared. Executing `M-x package-refresh-contents` didn't make things more predictable. But the point is, eventually the "missing" appeared.

Comment: Have you considered to provide a bug-report ( M-x report-emacs-bug ) ?